# How can I access a specific protected inherited member depending on the class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector, scope

Okay so I have `MainShop`(base class) then `SwordShop` and `BowShop`(derived classes) and another derived class called `Inventory`. I have a vector under protected in my base class, and when I access it from my derived classes it's okay, but each one has its own value. How can I set them all to have the same value?

```
//MainShop.h
#pragma once
class MainShop
{

private:
//some variables
protected:
    vector <string> WeaponInventory;
public:
//Some functions not related to the vector

};

//MainShop.cpp
/*Implementation of functions*/

//SwordShop.h
#pragma once
#include "MainShop.h"

class SwordShop: public MainShop
{
    private:
    int choice;
    public:
        void getSwordShop();
        void setWeaponSoldier(int i, string s);
        void soldierShop();
};

//SwordShop.cpp
#include "SwordShop.h"
void SwordShop::soldierShop()
{
    this->setWeaponSoldier(1, "1) Meito Ichimonji\n   +4 Damage\n   150Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(2, "2) Shusui\n   +10 Damage\n   230Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(3, "3) Elixir\n   +16 Damage\n   300Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(4, "4) Blade of scars\n   +24 Damage\n   550Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(5, "5) Ragnarok\n   +32 Damage\n   610Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(6, "6) Eternal Darkness\n   +40 Damage\n   690Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(7, "7) Masamune\n   +52 Damage\n   750Gold");
    this->setWeaponSoldier(8, "8) Soul Calibur\n   +60 Damage\n   900Gold");

    this->getSwordShop();

    cout << "What would you like to buy?";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
          WeaponInventory.push_back("Meito Ichimonji");
          cout << "You have Successfully Bought Meito Ichimonji\nIt has been added to your inventory\n";
            break;

        case 2:
          WeaponInventory.push_back("Shusui");
          cout << "You have Successfully Bought Shusui\nIt has been added to your inventory\n";
            break;
            //ETC

        default:
            cout << "Error! You have entered an invalid answer\nPlease try again";
            this->soldierShop();
    }
    cout << "your total items are: "<< WeaponInventory.size();
```

Okay So lets say I bought two items. Here it would display that I have 2 items. But if I do `cout << "your total items are: "<< WeaponInventory.size();` in my Inventory.cpp it would say I have 0! That's my problem.

```
void SwordShop::getSwordShop()
{
    //Display Choices
    for (map<int, string>::iterator iter = WeaponSoldier.begin(); iter != WeaponSoldier.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << iter->second << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void SwordShop::setWeaponSoldier(int i, string s)
{
    WeaponSoldier[i] = s;
}


//BowShop.h
#pragma once
#include "MainShop.h"

class BowShop: public MainShop
{
    private:
    int choice2;
    public:
        void getBowShop();
        void setWeaponArcher(int i, string s);
        void ArcherShop();
};

//BowShop.cpp
#include "BowShop.h"
void BowShop::ArcherShop()
{
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(1,"1) Arondight\n   +4 Damage\n   150Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(2,"2) Gugnir\n   +10 Damage\n   230Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(3,"3) Susano'\n   +16 Damage\n   300Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(4,"4) Longinus\n   +24 Damage\n   550Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(5,"5) Hrunting\n   +32 Damage\n   610Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(6,"6) Clarent\n   +40 Damage\n   690Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(7,"7) Shinigami\n   +52 Damage\n   750Gold");
    BowShop::setWeaponArcher(8,"8) Caliburn\n   +60 Damage\n   900Gold");

    this->getBowShop();//Display options

    cout << "What would you like to buy?";
    cin >> choice2;
    switch (choice2)
    {
        case 1:
                WeaponInventory.push_back("Arondight");
                cout << "You have Successfully Bought Arondight\nIt has been added to your inventory\n";
            break;

        case 2:
                WeaponInventory.push_back(" Gugnir");
                cout << "You have Successfully Bought  Gugnir\nIt has been added to your inventory\n";
            break;

        //ETC

        default:
            cout << "Error! You have entered an invalid answer\nPlease try again";
            this->ArcherShop();
    }
}

void BowShop::getBowShop()
{
    //Display Choices
    for (map<int, string>::iterator iter = WeaponArcher.begin(); iter != WeaponArcher.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << iter->second << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void BowShop::setWeaponArcher(int i, string s)
{
    WeaponArcher[i] = s;
}


//Inventory.h
#Pragma once
#include "MainShop.h"

class Inventory: public MainShop//access base class data like protected members
{
    private:
    int choice;
    public:
        void DisplayInventory();
        void DisplayStats();

};

//Inventory.cpp
#include "Inventory.h"

void Inventory::DisplayInventory()
{
    cout << "\nWhat do you want to do?\n1) Check Status\n2) Equip Weapons";//Equip what is in your inventory
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1: this->DisplayStats();
            break;
        case 2:cout << WeaponInventory.size() << endl;//debug
            if (!WeaponInventory.empty())//Make sure inventory is not empty
            {
                cout << "Your current Weapons are: \n";
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < WeaponInventory.size(); ++i)
                    cout << i << ") " << WeaponInventory[i] << endl;
            }
            else cout << "You do not currently have any items!";
        default: cout << "Error on switch!";
    }
}
```

Here every time I run it, it goes straight to the `else` and it displays that I do not have any items. I want to just have one vector for both my bow and Sword shops because vectors take up a lot of memory and my teacher said keep them to a minimum. So I just want one vector that takes in items from my bow class as well as my sword class, but for some reason it's acting as if I have multiple vectors, each with its own set of items. Please help!

Comment: instance variables are for the INSTANCE....  you can only share at the static level.

Comment: Yes, but every time i try, for example: In SwordShop.cpp i can do  MainShop shop; then i do shop.WeaponInventory.push_back("something"); It gives me an error saying Weapon Inventory is a protected member of MainShop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you want a static variable declared so ALL subclass instances have same value.

your question was about data, you can ONLY access protected members from within the class, touching "protected" members from outside of the class is not allowed.  You need to either change your protected variable to public OR add a public method to perform what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If i declare it static, then EVERYTHING that has to do with that static variable will have to be static as well?

Comment: no... the variable... your question was about data, you can ONLY access protected members from within the class, touching "protected" members from outside of the class is not allowed.  You need to either change your protected variable to public OR add a public method to perform what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This public method your talking about will have to be implemented in the base class? Because i already have public methods for accessing the vector such as `getSwordShop();` and `setWeaponSoldier(int i, string s);`

Comment: i'm only saying that the variable WeaponInventory is able to touched inside the main or subclass, not from anyplace else.  You pasted code earlier that was having errors due to accessibility.  That line of code must not belonged to a subclass, it must have belonged to a method inside a class that was not a subclass.